# Как правильно задать центр вращения для анимации SVG элемента?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation, smil

Есть *rect*, которому нужно задать анимацию поворота "туда-обратно", неважно через CSS-анимации или через SMIL, анимация всё равно простая. Но возникает трудность с определением точки, от которой производится поворот фигуры. Нужно чтобы он производился от середины нижней грани прямоугольника, но как определить эти координаты? Для наглядности я привёл свой ошибочный пример, где *circle* отображает точку от которой нужно совершить поворот.

```html
<svg>
  <style>
    svg {
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: grey;
    }
    rect {
      animation: anim 2s linear 3 alternate;
    }
    @keyframes anim {
    0% {  transform-origin: 75% 75%;
    transform: rotate(-15deg); }
    100% { transform-origin: 75% 75%;
    transform: rotate(15deg); }
    }
  </style>
  <rect width="30" height="50" fill="black" x="150" y="120"/>
  <circle r="3" cx="165" cy="170" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задайте `transform-origin` в пикселях, как и центр круга...

```css
svg {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
}
rect {
  animation: anim 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  transform-origin: 165px 170px;
}
@keyframes anim {
  0%   {transform: rotate(-10deg)}
  50%  {transform: rotate(370deg)}
  100% {transform: rotate(-10deg)}
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="100 100 140 140" style="height:90vh">
  <rect width="30" height="50" fill="black" x="150" y="120"/>
  <rect width="30" height="50" fill="black" x="150" y="120" style="animation-delay:0.2s"/>
  <rect width="30" height="50" fill="black" x="150" y="120"  style="animation-delay:0.4s"/>
  <circle r="3" cx="165" cy="170" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Вариант `SVG smil`

> Но возникает трудность с определением точки, от которой производится
>   поворот фигуры. Нужно чтобы он производился от середины нижней грани
>   прямоугольника, но как определить эти координаты?

- Определение координат центра вращения

Для прямоугольника   `<rect width="30" height="50" fill="black" x="150" y="120"/>`

координата **X** - центра вращения: координата левого верхнего угла прямоугольника (`x`) + `width/2`

`x = 150+30/2 = 165px`

координата **Y** центра вращения:

`y = 120 + 50 = 170px`

- Вращение одного прямоугольника

```css
 svg {
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: grey;
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >  
<circle r="3" cx="165" cy="170" fill="white"/>
<rect id="rect1" width="30" height="50" fill="black" x="150" y="120"/>  
  <animateTransform 
   xlink:href="#rect1"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="rotate"
   dur="4s"
   values="0 165 170;360 165 170;0 165 170;0 165 170"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
</svg>
```

- Вращение нескольких прямоугольников

Каждый прямоугольник поворачивается на разный угол.
Первый прямоугольник поворачивается на 45град, - `values="0 160 170;45 160 170"`
Второй на 90 град - `values="0 160 170;90 160 170"` и так далее

```css
svg {
      height: 45%;
      width: 45%;
      background-color: #d3d3d3;
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       viewBox="0 0 300 300" >   
   
<rect id="rect1" fill="#485AE4" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">
</rect> 
    <rect id="rect2" fill="#DCE44C" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">  
        <animateTransform   attributeName="transform"  type="rotate" begin="3s" dur="0.5s" 
        values="0 160 170;45 160 170" fill="freeze" /> 
 </rect> 
<rect id="rect3" fill="#4EE9DF" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">  
        <animateTransform   attributeName="transform"  type="rotate" begin="2.5s" dur="0.5s" 
        values="0 160 170;90 160 170" fill="freeze" /> 
  </rect>  
     <rect id="rect4" fill="purple" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">  
        <animateTransform   attributeName="transform"  type="rotate" begin="2s" dur="0.5s" 
        values="0 160 170;135 160 170" fill="freeze" /> 
  </rect> 
  <rect id="rect5" fill="yellowgreen" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">  
        <animateTransform   attributeName="transform"  type="rotate" begin="1.5s" dur="0.5s" 
        values="0 160 170;180 160 170" fill="freeze" /> 
  </rect>  
<rect id="rect6" fill="dodgerblue" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">  
      <animateTransform   attributeName="transform"  type="rotate" begin="1s" dur="0.5s" 
      values="0 160 170;225 160 170" fill="freeze" /> 
</rect>
   <rect id="rect7" fill="gold" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">  
      <animateTransform   attributeName="transform"  type="rotate" begin="0.5s" dur="0.5s" 
      values="0 160 170;270 160 170" fill="freeze" /> 
   </rect>   
    
<rect id="rect8" fill="red" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">  
  <animateTransform   attributeName="transform"  type="rotate" begin="0s" dur="0.5s" 
   values="0 160 170;315 160 170" fill="freeze"/> 
</rect> 
   

<circle r="4" cx="160" cy="170" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

**Вариант открытия веером. Запуск анимации от кнопки "Start"**

```html
<style>
    .container {
  width:50%;
  height:50%
        }
  svg {background-color: #d3d3d3;}
   
</style> 
<div class="container">  
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      viewBox="0 0 300 300" >   

  
<rect id="rect1" fill="#485AE4" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">
</rect> 
    <rect id="rect2" fill="#DCE44C" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">  
        <animateTransform id="an2"   attributeName="transform"  type="rotate" begin="gr1.click" dur="0.8s" 
        values="0 160 170;45 160 170" fill="freeze" /> 
 </rect> 
<rect id="rect3" fill="#4EE9DF" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">  
        <animateTransform id="an3"   attributeName="transform"  type="rotate" begin="gr1.click" dur="0.8s" 
        values="0 160 170;90 160 170" fill="freeze" /> 
  </rect>  
     <rect id="rect4" fill="purple" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">  
        <animateTransform id="an4"   attributeName="transform"  type="rotate" begin="gr1.click" dur="0.8s" 
        values="0 160 170;135 160 170" fill="freeze" /> 
  </rect> 
  <rect id="rect5" fill="yellowgreen" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">  
        <animateTransform id="an5"   attributeName="transform"  type="rotate" begin="gr1.click" dur="0.8s" 
        values="0 160 170;180 160 170" fill="freeze" /> 
  </rect>  
<rect id="rect6" fill="dodgerblue" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">  
      <animateTransform  id="an6" attributeName="transform"  type="rotate" begin="gr1.click" dur="0.8s" 
      values="0 160 170;225 160 170" fill="freeze" /> 
</rect>
   <rect id="rect7" fill="gold" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">  
      <animateTransform  id="an7" attributeName="transform"  type="rotate" begin="gr1.click" dur="0.8s" 
      values="0 160 170;270 160 170" fill="freeze" /> 
   </rect>   
    
<rect id="rect8" fill="red" width="20" height="50"  x="150" y="120" rx="7">  
  <animateTransform   attributeName="transform"  type="rotate" begin="gr1.click" dur="0.8s" 
   values="0 160 170;315 160 170" fill="freeze"/> 
</rect> 
  
<circle r="4" cx="160" cy="170" fill="white"/>
<g id="gr1" text-anchor="middle" >  
   <!-- кнопка -->
 <rect id="rect1" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="30"  fill="#1A2153"/>
  <text id="txt1" x="150" y="22" font-size="28" stroke="white" fill="white"  pointer-events="none" > Start</text>
  </g>

</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @anDev посмотрите ещё один ответ.